# Using flask in a unit test as a callback endpoint?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, flask

The REST interface I'm testing involves the use of an HTTP callback. I need a way to write a test against this interface. I test my primary REST server with Flask's `test_client` feature. One of the endpoints I test uses `requests` to talk to another server. I need a way to create that other server as part of the unit test.

My preference is to write another Flask server which works as the callback, but I'm not clear on how I can run this during the test. `run` is a blocking call thus my `setUp` function won't return. I could put it in a thread, but then I have a teardown issue (I don't know how to tell Flask to stop). I've also wonder if maybe the `test_client` can give me an actual endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad to receive a clear answer.

The right way to test it is with the `test_client`. Refer to [Testing Flask applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/) in Flask docs.

Also, you can use [Flask-Testing](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/) to help with the skeleton of your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You could mock the response data from the `requests` calls, using something like:

[httpmock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httmock/)

Comment: That's looks promising. It doesn't look like I'd be able to test a timeout, or HTTP level failure (like SSL invalid cert).

Comment: Timeouts you can just simulate by asserting the requests requests.exceptions.ConnectionError possibly